# can't disabled anchor tags using jquery... nither with "disabled" nor with e.preventDefault() during ajax call()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

now there is only problem not disabled anchor tag i had include ajax submit library which is working now i only want to disabl anchor during processing but i can't disabled niether with "disable" nor with e.preventDefault()

And thanks all of you for your help

```
        <?php } else if ($currStep == 1) { ?>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-offset-1">   
                    <form id="form-change-password" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('user/save_password'); ?>">   
                        <div class="form-group">  
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-md-3" style=" padding-left: 0px; ">New Password * </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm password"  id="inputfield1" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" placeholder="New Password" name="password">
                                <span class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">  
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-md-3" style=" padding-left: 0px; ">Confirm Password * </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm"  id="inputfield1" value="<?php echo set_value('cpassword'); ?>" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpassword">
                                <span class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">  
                            <label for="inputfield2" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'user/upate_step_status/2' ?>" class="nextBtn btn btn-primary pull-right "> Next </a>
                                <div class="loading-2 btn btn-default pull-right hidden" style="width: 70px">
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/frontend/img/loading-spinner-blue.gif'; ?>" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="save-2 submit btn btn-success pull-right">Save</button>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'user/upate_step_status/0' ?>" class=" btn nextBtn btn-default pull-right"> Back </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else if ($currStep == 2) { ?>
```

and i changed js to this

```
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script> $('.loading-2').hide();</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form-change-password').validate({// initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                cpassword: {
                    equalTo: ".password"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                password: " Enter Password with 6 minimum characters",
                cpassword: "Password not matched"
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                $("#form-change-password :input").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#form-change-password a").prop("disabled", true);
                $(".stepwizard-row a").prop("disabled", true);
                $(".loading-2").removeClass('hidden');
                $('.save-2, .loading-2').toggle();
                $('#form-change-password').ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        if (result == 1) {

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $("#form-change-password :input").prop("disabled", false);
                                $("#form-change-password a").click(function (e) {
                                    console.log("oye sabar ker");
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                });
                                $(".stepwizard-row a").prop("disabled", false);
                                $('.save-2, .loading-2').toggle();
                            }, 10000);
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all i do it by copying all  remove href attr and then again add href and its value after ajax call it works for me, if you have any better idea please tell me

```
<script> $('.loading-4').hide();</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form-update-profile').validate({// initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true
                },
                department: {
                    required: true
                },
                description: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                $(".loading-4").removeClass('hidden');
                $('.save-4, .loading-4').toggle();
                $('.messages-success, .messages-danger').removeClass('hidden').addClass('hidden');
                $("#form-update-profile :input").prop("disabled", true);
                var nextHref = $("#form-update-profile .next").attr("href");
                var backHref = $("#form-update-profile .back").attr("href");
                var linkpage0 = $(".stepwizard-step .first").attr("href");
                var linkpage1 = $(".stepwizard-step .second").attr("href");
                var linkpage2 = $(".stepwizard-step .third").attr("href");
                var linkpage3 = $(".stepwizard-step .fourth").attr("href");
                var linkpage4 = $(".stepwizard-step .fifth").attr("href");
                $("#form-update-profile a").removeAttr("href");
                $(".stepwizard-step a").removeAttr("href");
                $('#form-update-profile').ajaxSubmit({
                    error: function () {
                        $('.messages-danger .alert-danger').text("Some Error Occurred, Please try again");
                        $('.messages-danger').removeClass('hidden');
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        response = $.parseJSON(response);
                        if (response['status'] == true) {
                            $('.messages-success .alert-success').text(response['message']);
                            $('.messages-success').removeClass('hidden');
                        } else {
                            $('.messages-danger .alert-danger').text(response['message']);
                            $('.messages-danger').removeClass('hidden');
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("#form-update-profile .next").attr("href", nextHref);
                        $("#form-update-profile .back").attr("href", backHref);
                        $(".stepwizard-step .first").attr("href", linkpage0);
                        $(".stepwizard-step .second").attr("href", linkpage1);
                        $(".stepwizard-step .third").attr("href", linkpage2);
                        $(".stepwizard-step .fourth").attr("href", linkpage3);
                        $(".stepwizard-step .fifth").attr("href", linkpage4);
                        $("#form-update-profile :input").prop("disabled", false);
                        $("#form-update-profile input").val('');
                        $('.save-4, .loading-4').toggle();
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a comma missing.

Please change

```
                        cpassword :"Password not matched"
                }
        submitHandler: function() {
```

to

```
                        cpassword :"Password not matched"
                },
        submitHandler: function() {
```

Comment: now there is no error boss but porblem is that still nothings works thanks for your effort but actually i can't put whole code and jquery, ajax always disturb mee

Comment: @ZohaibHassan Are there any other errors in your JS console or php_error_log?

Comment: no sir nothing just a warning to using password field on unsecure page

Comment: submit handler is not trigger at all probably due to button type button

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after the messages block in your javascript.

I've standardised the indentation on the code so it's easier to read. This also makes it much easier to spot errors.

In addition, you had inconsistent spaces around colons, so I tidied those too.

Edit: jQuery matches the id of the input, not the name.

```
<script>
    function savepassword() {
        $('#password').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                cpassword: {
                    equalTo: "#inputfield1"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                password: " Enter Password with 6 minimum characters",
                cpassword: "Password not matched"
            },
            submitHandler: function() {
                $('.save-2, .loading-2').toggle();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('user/save_password'); ?>",
                    data: {
                        password: $('#password input[name="password"]').val(),
                        cpassword: $('#password input[name="cpassword"]').val()
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
                $('.save-2, .loading-2').toggle();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah. You're using a different name to the id of the form elements. I'll edit to fix

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you have asked. But the best way to disabled page or sections when processing is by adding an overlay element using css and also with the loading icon preferably. This would avoid all the hassle and also provides better presentation.

Comment: i want to do it on run time using jquery or any other like thiss